# How are surrogate pairs calculated?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, utf-16

If a unicode code point uses 17 bits or more, how are the surrogate pairs calculated?

Comment: What do you mean? Unicode code-point is not 17-bit, and UTF-8 doesn't use surrogate pairs.

Comment: Roughly 21 bits are required for a Unicode codepoint. It though use 17 planes of each 65536 codepoints, which results in 1114112 codepoints in total. Which is about 20.087 bits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unicode code points are scalar values which range from 0x000000 to 0x10FFFF. Thus they are are 21 bit integers, not 17 bit.

Surrogate pairs are a mechanism of the UTF-16 form.  This represents the 21-bit scalar values as one or two 16-bit code units.

- Scalar values from 0x000000 to 0x00FFFF are represented as a single 16-bit code unit, from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF.
- Scalar values from 0x00D800 to 0x00DFFF are not characters in Unicode, and so they will never occur in a Unicode character string.
- Scalar values from 0x010000 to 0x10FFFF are represented as two 16-bit code units. The first code unit encodes the upper 11 bits of the scalar value, as a code unit ranging from 0xD800-0xDBFF. There's a bit of trickiness to encode values from 0x01-0x10 in four bits. The second code unit encodes the lower 10 bits of the scalar value, as a code unit ranging from 0xDC00-0xDFFF.

This is explained in detail, with sample code, in the Unicode consortium's FAQ, [UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html).  That FAQ refers to the section of the Unicode Standard which has even more detail.

Comment: The sample code in the FAQ deals with mapping surrogate pairs to code points. The question was about the opposite-direction mapping; it is presented in D91 in Chapter 3 of the Unicode Standard, http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch03.pdf

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, as I read FAQ entry [Q: What’s the algorithm to convert from UTF-16 to character codes?](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html#utf16-3), I see sample code for mapping both from character code to UTF-16 and back again, though the title doesn't promise it.

Answer (score 7):

If it is code you are after, here is how a single codepoint is encoded in UTF-16 and UTF-8 respectively.

A single codepoint to UTF-16 codeunits:

```
if (cp < 0x10000u)
{
   *out++ = static_cast<uint16_t>(cp);
}
else
{
   *out++ = static_cast<uint16_t>(0xd800u + (((cp - 0x10000u) >> 10) & 0x3ffu));
   *out++ = static_cast<uint16_t>(0xdc00u + ((cp - 0x10000u) & 0x3ffu));
}
```

A single codepoint to UTF-8 codeunits:

```
if (cp < 0x80u)
{
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>(cp);
}
else if (cp < 0x800u)
{
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp >> 6) & 0x1fu | 0xc0u);
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp & 0x3fu) | 0x80u);
}
else if (cp < 0x10000u)
{
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp >> 12) & 0x0fu | 0xe0u);
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>(((cp >> 6) & 0x3fu) | 0x80u);
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp & 0x3fu) | 0x80u);
}
else
{
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp >> 18) & 0x07u | 0xf0u);
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>(((cp >> 12) & 0x3fu) | 0x80u);
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>(((cp >> 6) & 0x3fu) | 0x80u);
   *out++ = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp & 0x3fu) | 0x80u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hopefully somewhat more beginner-friendly exposition.

The surrogate code points are in the range 0xD800-0xDF00. The first half of this space is used for the high half of the surrogate and the second half for the low half.

So, to encode U+10000, you split the remainder above 0x10000 into two halves, and cram them into the slots available.

```
D8 00 DC 00
```

Similarly, to encode U+10FFFF, you get

```
DB FF DF FF
```

In other words, the values from D800 to DBFF have their D800 part masked off, and the remainder is used for the first ten bits of the value we want to encode. Similarly, the values from DC00 to DFFF have DC00 masked off, and the remainder is used for the low ten bits of the encoded value.

By definition, the base for all these code points is 0x10000, so that does not have to be explicitly encoded, just the offset from this base.

```
U+00010000 = base 0x00010000 + 0x00000
= 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
  mmnn nnnn nnpp qqqq qqqq

U+0010FFFF = base 0x00010000 + 0xFFFFF
= 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
  mmnn nnnn nnpp qqqq qqqq
```

... where mmnnnnnnnn in hex is xxx and ppqqqqqqqq is yyy

```
1101 10mm  nnnn nnnn   D8+xxx   1110 11pp  qqqq qqqq   DC+yyy
-----------------------------   -----------------------------
1101 1000  0000 0000   D800     1110 1100  0000 0000   DC00
1101 1011  1111 1111   DBFF     1110 1111  1111 1111   DFFF
```

Comment: Where did this come from in the first place? D800DC00 @triplee

Comment: Those are the starting points of the surrogate ranges. If it's in that range it's a surrogate; otherwise, it's not. Conversely, to create a surrogate, you have to use those "magical constants"; that's how this mechanism is defined.

Comment: magical constants thank u :) @triplee